# Why an Out Parameter can be left unassigned in projects targeting .NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, .net-standard, out-parameters

I tried the below code in a C# (ClassLibrary) project that targets .NET Standard 2.0 and it compiles successfully, meanwhile it gives an error in another project targeting .NET Core 3.1

```
private void SetOffset(out TimeSpan offset)
{
    return;
}
```

The error in .NET Core project is as expected:

> CS0177: The out parameter 'offset' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because if struct contains no accessible fields, it is considered assigned. For example:

```
private void SetOffset(out Test offset)
{
    return;
}

struct Test {
    void DoSomething() {

    }
}
```

Compiles just fine in .NET Core 3.1 (and other .NET versions).

Now, there was (is?) an issue in .NET Standard reference libraries (those libraries basically only contain a "stub" and a "real" library is actually used when code is run) that private fields were not included, so `TimeSpan` in .NET Standard 2.0 reference library doesn't contain any accessible fields, and so is considered assigned by compiler by the same reason as `Test` struct above. This issue is discussed in more details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29319). Actually it might be more complicated that "doesn't contain any fields", because as you can read in the linked issue - some fields might be ignored by compiler in such reference assembly. But in the end result is the same - compiler treats this structure as containing no accessible fields and allows the usage in question.

Answer (score -2):

Is like this:
The compiler can't know if is will be initialized, then you need initialize always

```
private void SetOffset(out TimeSpan offset)
{
        offset = new TimeSpan(); //reset all the timespan
}
```

You can do sth like this too:

```
private void SetOffset(out TimeSpan offset)
{
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 8, 0, 15);
        DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18, 13, 30, 30);
        offset = date1 - date2; //offset.Days will be -229 an will be passed a initialized timespan by minus
}
```

Comment: The question is why the code compiles when it shouldn't, not how to make the code compile.